# Does threading module in python provide true parallelism?

Tags: java, python, multithreading, parallel-processing, pthreads

By creating threads using threading module in Python, do threads actually run in parallel?

Suppose I have two threads. Both of them perform the sorting operation.

Are these threads performing the sorting operation at the same time on multiple processors, or is the parallelism being achieved by preemption between these two operations?

Simply: Does threading module in python provide true parallelism? Do the two threads actually run at the same time on multiple processors that are available?

Also which languages exploit true parallelism?

Answer (score 0):

Python has a global mutex, [Global Interpreter Lock (GIL)](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock), that actually prevents multiple native threads from executing Python bytecodes at once.
So I suppose you can say there's no "true" parallelism with python threads.